# Column shifting left in SSRS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

Weird thing happening on our Reporting services 2010 server. I created a report based on this data :

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Certification</td><td>Contenant</td><td>Lundi</td><td>Mardi</td><td>Mercredi</td><td>Jeudi</td><td>Vendredi</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>NON-CERT</td><td>BALLOT</td><td>47</td><td>74</td><td>71</td><td>21</td><td>40</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>NON-CERT</td><td>CAISSE</td><td>8</td><td>5</td><td>10</td><td>19</td><td>  23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>NON-CERT</td><td>GRAND</td><td>218</td><td>119</td><td>165</td><td>74</td><td>110</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>NON-CERT</td><td>PETIT</td><td>50</td><td>68</td><td>55</td><td>24</td><td>    21</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>TOTAL</td><td>BALLOT</td><td>47</td><td>74</td><td>71</td><td>21</td><td>  40</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>TOTAL</td><td>CAISSE</td><td>8</td><td>5</td><td>10</td><td>19</td><td>23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>TOTAL</td><td>GRAND</td><td>218</td><td>119</td><td>165</td><td>74</td><td>   110</td><td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>TOTAL</td><td>PETIT</td><td>50</td><td>68</td><td>55</td><td>24</td><td>21</td><td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It's a simple Stored Procedure getting numbers per day (sorry it's in french). I built the report in Visual Studio 2015 and on the preview page, it's perfect. But whenever I deploy it to the server it looks like this :
[Result Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhevg.png)

So the problem is that it shifts days column to the left and sets the last one to 0. I tried doing the report in Visual Studio 2010 but to no avail.

Anybody has an idea as to what the problem is?

Thanks you

[UPDATE 10/03/2016]
I hardcoded values in my stored procedure and the report does NOT shift columns?!? This is getting weirder by the minute.

[UPDATE2 10/03/2016]
Here's a pic from the preview in Visual Studio 2015
[Preview in VS2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFyvO.png)

[UPDATE3 10/03/2016]
I sent the report to a Reporting Server 2014 and it works perfectly.

Comment: Are you sure the datasource of one of the servers isn't wrong? That's usually the issue with differences in deployment. I would make sure you get the same results when using the datasource (`Report->Manage->Data Sources`) that the deployed report is using.

Comment: Yes the datasource is good since it's a shared datasource for every report on our server. And I wouldn't get any data if it wasn't good.

Comment: From your updated above, it sounds like the issue is with your stored procedures. Can you get the results of your report query from both sources and compare them like in your SQL Data pic? Maybe add a simple table for troubleshooting if you don't have database access.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question properly. There's only 1 source in my report.

Comment: I was thinking that your datasource in DEV might be different than the datasource that the report uses when it gets deployed to the report server. I thought that if you made a simple table to display the data, you might see a difference between the different deployments.

Comment: What browser are you using, I have run into weird issues with SSRS using different browsers.  IE works the best but even certain versions can have issues.

Comment: No I was done with developpement so I "installed" my stored procedure on the production server and connected my report to it.
@Scott : I'm using IE11 in Windows 10 because we had trouble with Chrome and Firefox. Even Edge doesn't work properly with Reporting Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it. The problem came from the DATEPART sql function. It uses the regional settings for the first day of the week. So on the SQL server and my computer, the first day of the week is Sunday (7) but on the reporting server, the first day of the week is Monday(1) and that's why everything was shifted to the left.

To fix this, I added this code in my stored procedure :

SET DATEFIRST 7

and voila..